# How to get livestock in Banished

Tags: banished

How do you get other types of livestock in Banished? I started with chickens, but can't find a way to get Cows or Sheep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trade for other types of livestock once you get a trading post up and running and a merchant arrives who has them to trade.

Comment: Haha, Yeah this is actually on the product description page having just read this I was going to answer this :D

Comment: Yeah I had trouble finding it when I was playing until I realized I could just look in the help file. I had tried googling it to no avail so I thought I'd add it somewhere someone else might find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have built a trading post but none of the traders that visit you have lifestock, build another one. Each trading post you build is visited by a different random selection of traders.